# How to specify a non-linear interaction term in a linear model

Tags: regression, logistic, interaction

Say I have 2 continuous variables (x & y) in a logit model. I want to test the following hypotheses in the model:

1. For low values of x, increasing the value of y will increase the value of the response variable
2. For high values of x, increasing the value of y will decrease the value of the response variable

Is there a way to specify this using interaction terms? I have only used interaction terms in which y has a linear impact on the effect of x on the response variable.

Comment: $y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_{x}x_i + \beta_{z}z_i + \beta_{xz}xz_i + \varepsilon_i$?

Comment: Logit already does this to some degree because you have a nonlinear link function wrapped around the linear-in-parameters index function part, so that the marginal effect depends on the values of all the covariates. You can also add interactions like @Alexis suggested. More on that at datacolada.org/57.

Comment: @Alexis suggestion is correct. A "non-linear interaction term" would refer to a question like: "For men, the correlation is positive and linear; while for women, it is negative and is quadratic" or something.

Comment: Thank you all. Stupid question, but what does zi refer to in your equation above, Alexis? Just want to make sure I understand correctly. Thanks.

Comment: Based on Alexis's formula above, the coefficient for the interaction term won't vary based on whether x is low or high. In other words, the coefficient should be positive for low values of x and negative for high values of x.

Comment: Interaction terms are always non-linear. If the effects are linearly separable, then there not interaction effects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my comment I wrote that you could model the kind of nonlinearity you describe with a model such as the below model, which incorporates a "multiplicative interaction term."

$$\text{logit}({y_i}) = \beta_0 + \beta_{x}x_{i} + \beta_{z}z_{i} + \beta_{xz}xz_{i} + \varepsilon_{i}$$

Consider such a model where:

- $y_i$ is the value of the dependent (response) variable for the $i^{\text{th}}$ subject,
- $x_i$ is the value of the independent variable $x$ for the $i^{\text{th}}$ subject,
- $z_i$ is the value of the independent variable $z$ for the $i^{\text{th}}$ subject,
- $xz_{i}$ is the value of the product of $x$ and $z$ for the $i^{\text{th}}$ subject, and
- $\varepsilon_i$ is the value of the model residual for the $i^{\text{th}}$ subject.

Let's assume that $x$ and $y$ are continuous variables, but that $z$ is a nominal ($0/1$) variable. If $z=0$ then $\beta_{z}z_{i}=0$ and $\beta_{z}xz_{i}=0$, and the above model reduces to a simple bivariate logit regression of $y$ onto $x$, where $\beta_0$ is the $y$ intercept, and $\beta_{x}$ is how much the log-odds of $y$ changes given a 1-unit increase in $x$. However, if $z_{i}=1$, then the $y$ intercept becomes $\beta_0 + \beta_{z}z_{i}$ or $\beta_0 + \beta_{z}$ (since $z=1$). (Right? Because if $z_{i}=1$ then you add $\beta_{z}$, which is a scalar constant, to $\beta_{0}$: another scalar constant.) Similarly, the effect on the log-odds of $y$ of a 1-unit increase of $x$ becomes $\beta_{x} + \beta_{xz}$. (Right? Because if $z =1$, then $\beta_{xz}xz_{i} = \beta_{xz}x_{i}$, so when $x$ increases by 1-unit, the log-odds of $y$ changes by $\beta_{x}$, but also by $\beta_{xz}$.)

Application of this kind of mutiplicative interaction model is not limited to $z$ being nominal, however: $z$ can be continuous as well, in which case you simply need to plug the the specific value of $z$ to understand the effect of $x$ on the log-odds of $y$ and vice versa. **With multiplicative interactions neither the effect of $\boldsymbol{x}$ nor the effect of $\boldsymbol{z}$ on $\boldsymbol{y}$ can be understood independently of one another.**

**Example**

In the below graph we see two logistic curves of $y$ as modeled on $z$, the black one for values of $x = 0.1$ (i.e. "low"), and the red one for values of $x = 0.9$ (i.e. "high"). When $x$ is low the effect of $z$ on the log odds of $y$ is positive (i.e. as $z$ increases, the log odds of $y$ increases). When $x$ is high the effect of $z$ on the log odds of $y$ is negative (i.e. as $z$ increases, the log odds of $y$ decreases). This speaks precisely to your original question. The numerical specification of this relationship is:

$$\text{logit}({y_i}) = 1.25x_{i} + 2z_{i} - 3.75xz_{i}$$

Notice that by substituting $x_i = 0.1$, the (black line) model simplifies to one where the effect of $z$ is *positive*:

$$\begin{align*}\text{logit}({y_i}) & = 1.25\times 0.1 + 2z_{i} - 3.75\times 0.1 \times z_{i}\\
& = 0.125 + 2z_{i} - 0.375z_{i}\\
& = 0.125 + 1.625z_{i}\end{align*}$$

And notice that by substituting $x_i = 0.9$, the (red line) model simplifies to one where the effect of $z$ is *negative*:

$$\begin{align*}\text{logit}({y_i}) & = 1.25 \times 0.9 + 2z_{i} - 3.75 \times 0.9 \times z_{i}\\
& = 1.125 + 2z_{i} - 3.375z_{i}\\
& = 1.125 - 1.375z_{i}\end{align*}$$

[image: Graph of Y vs Z when X is low (black) and high (red)]

Comment: Thanks for this clear explanation, Alexis. What I'm trying to model, however, is the situation in which the coefficient of the interaction term in your expression above varies depending on the value of say the 'x' variable. As an example, what if for certain values of x (say lower values of x) an increase in z will increase the value of y whereas for higher values of x an increase in z will decrease the value of y. The interaction term above only has a single coefficient and presumably wouldn't account for this varying effect by the level of the x variable. Appreciate your thoughts on this.

Comment: 1/2 1/2 @newcoder Ah I see. That sounds like you are trying to model a **nonlinearity in the effect of $\boldsymbol{x}$ on $\boldsymbol{y}$**, is that correct? You could do this by switching to a nonparametric regression, and if you are truly compelled to produce parametric estimates to a nonlinear least squares regression (i.e. explicitly articulate a logit model nonlinear in $x$ like $y_{i} = \frac{e^{\beta_0 +f(\Theta, x_{i}) + \text{etc.}}}{1 + e^{\beta_0 +f(\Theta, x_{i}) + \text{etc.}}}$). I often do the latter after being informed about reasonable functional forms using the former.

Comment: 2/2 But my above comment hints at an answer to a separate question than the one you asked at the top of the page, and my answer truly does answer your original question. Take a moment to look at the model in my answer, and ask yourself what happens if $\beta_{x}$ & $\beta_{z}$ are both positive, and $\beta_{xz} <0$.

Comment: Thanks for your robust explanations, Alexis. I appreciate you taking the time to respond. 
I still don't understand unfortunately how the model above yields different interaction coefficients depending on the value of x for example. For example, when x is high, coefficient on x/z interaction is high and when x is low, coefficient on x/z interaction is low. In your specification above, the interaction coefficient doesn't appear to change based on varying values of x. Am I missing something?

Comment: @newcoder Yes. You are missing my previous comment.  See my edited answer with example and graphic at the end, where the effect of $z$ on the response varies by values of $x$.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you want:

1. A two-way interaction, $XZ$, between $X$ and $Z$. This will estimate the expected change in the response for a 1 unit change in $X$, when $Z$ also changes by 1 unit.
2. If you want this two-way interaction also to also vary with $X$ then you can interact the two-way interaction with $X$, which will be $X^2Z$. This 3-way interaction will estimate the expected change in the response for a 1 unit change in $X$ when the interaction $XZ$ also changes by 1 unit.

Comment: This builds in a strong assumption of a quadratic relationship **in logit space**. Try playing with a graphing calculator some time: that's a weird shape, it is not a parabola (right? logit space is bounded between 0 and 1), and that is a strong assumption to make absent compelling evidence or theory to start with.

Answer (score 1):

X1 =  I(x>a)

X2=  I (x<b)

Logit (Response ) = beta0 + betax * x + betay * x + betax1y * X1 * y + betax2y * X2 * y

Then X1*y is activated when x is above a, X2* y when x is below b.
You can exclude betay*y if you think that response is only through y*x terms.
A and b are exogenous parameters in this model, so either outside knowledge or additional testing on which fit best is needed.

Comment: I like this solution, Diana. If I'm understanding correctly, you're saying that I can essentially create new variables that capture various levels of x and then put in as interactions so there can be different coefficients depending on the value of x? Any suggestion for how to make this more continuous? If I only include two levels (i.e., x > a and x < b), I'm essentially treating all values of x that fall in those ranges similarly.

Comment: @newcoder  yes, here would be betax1y is by how much the effect of y is larger when x is above a. and betax2y - when x1 is below b.  You are saying Response = beta x a(X) x Y, where a(X) >0 if x is low and a(X)<0 when x is high.  My first answer is to introduce a new variable which is a(X) and then estimate beta. First suggestion was  a(X) = beta1 x  I(x>a) + beta2 x I(x<b). A continuous version is a(X) = (neutral level of X - X).  So logit(Response) = beta x (C- X) x Y, then if X is above C, the impact is negative and it gets bigger as X goes lower and vice versa. You can separate the slope

Comment: the slope for high and low X by introducing (C-X)*I(X>C) and (X-C)*I(X<C) as X1 and X2 and regressing on Y x X1 + Y x X2.  Or can smooth it to log(X-C)*I{X>C), log (C-X)*I(X<C). However, the more complex the function, the more questions of why the functional form is what you've chosen could be, so you might want to keep it simple